# F# List split,divide

Tags: list, split, f#, divide

i'm trying to solve an exercice in F#. I have to write a code that can differentiate between a book and a movie, and put it as book or a movie in a list. It can differentiate both by the filesize because books have no filesize. For exemple, if I put a Book in, the code has to add it in the list as a Book and same for the movie. I link a sample result and the input. Thank you in advance.

```
type Movie =
    { movieName: string
      duration: Nat
      fileSize: Nat }

type Book =
    { bookName: string
      pages: Nat }

type Activity =
    | Watch of Movie
    | Read of Book


let rec createActivities(hl: (string * Nat * Nat) list): Activity list = 
    match hl with
      | [] -> []
      | x::xs -> ....
```

Here are the inputs:

```
createActivities([
                "The Hobbit"                , 304N, 0N
                "The Fellowship of the Ring", 228N, 50N
                "The Name of the Wind"      , 662N, 0N
                "The Emoji Movie"           , 86N , 1024N
                "The Hobbit"                , 164N, 9001N
                "The Fellowship of the Ring", 700N, 0N
```

Result:

```
[
                Read { bookName = "The Hobbit"; pages = 304N }
                Watch { movieName = "The Fellowship of the Ring"; duration = 228N; fileSize = 50N }
                Read { bookName = "The Name of the Wind"; pages = 662N }
                Watch { movieName = "The Emoji Movie"; duration = 86N; fileSize = 1024N }
                Watch { movieName = "The Hobbit"; duration = 164N; fileSize = 9001N }
                Read { bookName = "The Fellowship of the Ring"; pages = 700N }
            ]
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you struggling with? I imagine you want to replace the `...` in your `createActivities` with the actual implementation - what is the logic that you want to implement there?

Comment: I want to use an recursive logic.

Answer (score 2):

Match expressions in F# can be quite advanced, with sub-matches inside various parts of the match expression. For example, the `x::xs` case in your match expression can be turned into `(name, duration, filesize) :: xs`. And if you specify a value for one of those, then it would only match when that part of the tuple had that value. With that in mind, I'd write your match expression as something like this:

```
let rec createActivities(hl: (string * Nat * Nat) list): Activity list = 
    match hl with
      | [] -> []
      | (name, pages, 0N) :: xs -> Read { bookName = name; pages = pages } :: createActivities xs
      | (name, duration, fileSize) :: xs -> Watch { movieName = name; duration = duration; fileSize = fileSize } :: createActivities xs
```

How this works is that the `match` cases will be processed in order from top to bottom, and the first one that matches will be used. So if the tuple as a `0N` as its third element, the second match case will be used, otherwise the third match case will be used. So the match expression can be kept quite simple and clean-looking.

Comment: thanks for u help. I tested it but it drop an error to the "0N". Error : "Non-primitive numeric literal constants cannot be used in pattern matches because they can be mapped to multiple different types through the use of a NumericLiteral module. Consider using replacing with a variable, and use 'when <variable> = <constant>' at the end of the match clause."

Comment: Then you'll need to use F#'s built-in `int` type instead of `Nat`. Alternately if you really want to use `Nat`, then do what that error message suggests, and use a `when` clause. E.g., `| (name,pages, zero) :: xs when zero = 0N -> Read { ... }`

Comment: thanks to u help i could resolve the problem. I changed my code with an if.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the Problem like this. Thanks for help.

```
let rec createActivities(hl: (string * Nat * Nat) list): Activity list =    
  match hl with 
  | [] -> []
  | (name, pagesorduration, Size) :: xs -> 
    if Size = 0N then Read { bookName = name; pages = pagesorduration } :: createActivities(xs) 
    else Watch { movieName = name; duration = pagesorduration; fileSize = Size } :: createActivities xs
```